# how to enable keep sections in generated dao classes in greendao

Tags: android, greendao

setenabledKeepSections enables keep sections in the entity classes. Is there any property with which we could enable keep sections in the entityDAO classes as well?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately there seems not to be a way. What are you trying to retain in the daoClasses? May be we can help you work around the need to do this.